# как сделать так чтобы Text не выходил за границы в QML

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick

Как можно сделать так, чтобы в Text символы не выходили за границу ProgressBar или любого другого элемента? если символы выходят за границу они должны исчезать .

```
ProgressBar {
            id: progressBarDuration
            anchors.verticalCenter: controlRect.verticalCenter
            anchors.left: controlRect.left
            anchors.leftMargin: rectBackground.width / marginLeftRight
            value: 1
            width: 400
            style: touchStyle

            Text {
                anchors.verticalCenter: progressBarDuration.verticalCenter
                anchors.left: progressBarDuration.left
                anchors.leftMargin: getWidth(rectBackground.width, 10)
                anchors.right: progressBarDuration.right
                text: qsTr("texgfdshgfjdkghfdkghfdfgdsfdsslhgjfdshgjfdskjgfdshklghft")
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно использовать свойство [elide](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-text.html#elide-prop) у Text